# Ways to encrypt Installed app and web service

Tags: java, http, ssl, encryption, https

I am looking for advise on how to encrypt a command line application.
I envisage a command line app that interacts with a web service. I want the messages between the app and the web service to be encrypted.

I know that SSL certificates are the common use for encrypting with web services however if i have a single app that many people take and use on the command line of their machines each will have to have a SSL certificate.

Is there another way to encrypt the communication?

Note: I am building both the web service and command line application so can match up the encryption if needed.

Thanks

Comment: *"[...] each will have to have a SSL certificate."* - So? What's the problem? What do you want to protect against? Do you want to hide the transmitted data from the user? If so, then this is really not possible, because they can decompile and manipulate your application.

Comment: I want to encrypt the transmitted data i.e., the http headers and body. And if the client side has to have a certificate, will it not have to be unique for each client? How would i go about that for a single distributed app?

Comment: *"will it not have to be unique for each client?"* - Every instance of your app should have the *same server certificate* if they are talking to the *same server (infrastructure)*. I don't see why you need multiple certificates.

Comment: There are Several third party jars already there You may google it. and use as  per your convenient.. Thank You

Comment: Apologies, the clients will have to generate private keys to interact with the server? They all cannot have the same public and private keys I thought. I am a noob at this sort of thing, thanks for the assistance btw

Comment: @VikrantKashyap I have done some googling and I have not stumbled across these jars, hence I am asking the community. Is this a specific type of encryption i can google to get these specific jars?

Comment: i will recommend you to go with AES Encryption Ihave used this earlier

Comment: @VikrantKashyap How will you handle the key exchanges? Why do you feel this is better than using HTTPS? Hint: It isn't.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to encrypt the transmitted data i.e., the http headers and body.

HTTPS with a server certificate (no need to client certificate in your case) can do it. Nobody between your client and your server will be able to read or modify the content of the transmitted data (url, headers and body).

The server will present his certificate to your client. With that your client can confirm the identity of the server. Then they can exchange informations securely.

If you need to identify the client to your server, you can use a client certificate (but it's not the only method)

Note that because of DNS and SNI, somebody on the network can still know which domain your client connect to.

Comment: The url is of course visible, just not the path and query.

Comment: @zaph what do you mean ? With https if I visit https://example.com/secret.html ONLY my browser and the website know that I want to visits /secret.html : the path is encrypted.

Comment: Consider `https://example.com/secret.html?password=mypassword`, The address is available (not encrypted), the path and quarry are encrypted.

Comment: @zaph yes, in your example, "example.com/secret/path?password=password", example.com transmitted in clear text (unencrypted, so available for attackers) and the path "/secret/path" with the query "?password=password" is transmitted encrypted.